# How to escape Unicode with JSON.toString() method in jetty-util-ajax?

Tags: java, json, unicode, jetty, amazon-device-messaging

Is it please possible to escape UTF-8 characters when using `JSON.toString()` method in [jetty-util-ajax](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/current/org/eclipse/jetty/util/ajax/package-summary.html) package?

I understand that the package might be an internal library, but until now it works well for me in a servlet which among other tasks sends push
notifications to mobile phones via FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) and ADM (Amazon Device Messaging).

However my problem with is that ADM does not accept any
UTF-8 chars (in my case Cyrillic) and reproducibly fails with the rather
*misleading* error message (Amazon talks about XML in all its error messages while [their API expects JSON data being POSTed](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/adm/send-message.html)):

```
<SerializationException>
<Message>Could not parse XML</Message>
</SerializationException>

java.lang.IllegalStateException:
unknown char '<'(60) in |||<SerializationException>|  <Message>Could
not parse XML</Message>|</SerializationException>||
```

So is there maybe some possibility in Jetty 9.4.8.v20171121 to *encode* the chars?

Here is my Java code:

```
// this string is POSTed to ADM server
public String toAdmBody() {
    Map<String, Object> root = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
    root.put("data", data);
    data.put("body", mBody);
    // ADM does not accept integers for some reason
    data.put("gid", String.valueOf(mGid));
    // HOW TO ENCODE UTF-8 CHARS TO \uXXXX HERE?
    return JSON.toString(root);
}

private void postMessage(String registrationId, int uid, String jsonStr) {
    mHttpClient.POST(String.format("https://api.amazon.com/messaging/registrations/%1$s/messages", registrationId))
        .header(HttpHeader.ACCEPT, "application/json; charset=utf-8")
        .header(HttpHeader.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json; charset=utf-8")
        .header(HttpHeader.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + mAccessToken)
        .header("X-Amzn-Type-Version", "com.amazon.device.messaging.ADMMessage@1.0")
        .header("X-Amzn-Accept-Type", "com.amazon.device.messaging.ADMSendResult@1.0")
        // add registrationID and notification body - for retrying after fetching token
        .attribute("registrationId", registrationId)
        .attribute("body", jsonStr)
        .content(new StringContentProvider(jsonStr))
        .send(mMessageListener);
}
```

When looking at the Jetty source code [JSON.java](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.x/jetty-util-ajax/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/util/ajax/JSON.java) there is some *decoding* happening (i.e. from `\uXXXX` to UTF-8 chars):

```
case 'u':
    char uc = (char)((TypeUtil.convertHexDigit((byte)source.next()) << 12)
            + (TypeUtil.convertHexDigit((byte)source.next()) << 8)
            + (TypeUtil.convertHexDigit((byte)source.next()) << 4) 
            + (TypeUtil.convertHexDigit((byte)source.next())));
    scratch[i++] = uc;
    break;
```

But how to do the reverse thing?

Comment: That JSON parse is also wrong, it doesn't support 3 or 4 byte decoding.  Plus why are you getting an XML parse exception while asking about JSON?

Comment: Joakim, that is the ADM backend, they always fail with supposed XML errors for some reason. In reality [their API expects JSON data](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/adm/send-message.html). My code works well with English-only chars. But fails when I add a single Russian letter to my JSON payload.

Comment: Amazon ADM apparently isn't honoring your `Accept` header, its sending you XML even though you didn't include that in your `Accept` header.

Comment: Thanks +1 but no, it is just a misleading error message by ADM backend, really.

Comment: This has been filed as a new issue btw https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/2391

Comment: What specific character is giving you problems?

Comment: Hmm, right now any character and any heading works... Seems to be the ADM backend issue then, sorry (I had it since days...) I think my question is still valid though: if there is a way to encode UTF-8 chars to `\uXXXX` when using jetty-util-ajax?

Answer (score 1):

The ContentProvider's are the source of the `Content-Type`, not your manually set header.

Change your ...

```java
.content(new StringContentProvider(jsonStr))
```

to ...

```java
.content(new StringContentProvider(jsonStr, "application/json", StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
```

as the default for `StringContentProvider` is `text/plain` (not JSON)

Comment: Ok, I will try that and report back. (However for english-only payload my code works)

Comment: Unfortunately, same "XML" error with `.content(new StringContentProvider(jsonStr, "application/json", StandardCharsets.UTF_8))`

Comment: In jetty 12 version this JSON.toString() is removed, any suggestion how to use the new version ?